# Htaccess Condition Not Working When Link is Opened on New Window

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Basically, I want to forbid access to a certain folder (called images) if the url path of HTTP Referer does not match a list of substrings ( ex. aa.php, bb.php) ;
I tried

```
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}   !(aa\.php).*  [NC]   
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}   !(bb\.php).*  [NC]   
  RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

However, it doesn't work when I right click Open Link In New Window when I mouseover the image links. For instance, on a page named ccc.php, the image link when clicked and opened on a new tab still displays the jpg on the browser instead of displaying the Forbidden Error message.

This also does not work when links are opened on new tab.

```
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}   !(aa\.php).*  [NC,OR]   
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}   !(bb\.php).*  [NC]   
  RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

as well as single condition

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}   !(aa\.php).*  [NC]    
 RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Are you sure your images aren't being cached by your browser?

Comment: I believe I disabled cache         
       `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />`

Comment: Also this problem only arises when opening links on new tab. Otherwise, it works fine. Thanks

Comment: Those meta tags don't pertain to the actual images (which are requested individually), they pertain to the HTML page that has the meta tags